# Free font containing all ISO 4217 currency symbols

Tags: font-recommendation

Can you please suggest a font(free for commercial use) that supports all the ISO 4217 symbols?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little. Do you need it for print or web? Where have you looked? Are there particular symbols you haven't been able to find fonts with? I think this is an interesting question, but you're more likely to get an answer if you put in more then one sentence to show the community you're serious.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [list](http://www.xe.com/symbols.php) of ISO 4217 currency symbols.

Code 2000 used to support all the currency symbols. Arial Unicode MS supports most of the currency symbols. But Code 2000 is no longer actively maintained. Any similar fonts will be useful I guess.

Comment: It is more useful to give excerpts from links you provide. You know, the morning sun never lasts a day...